# Click event with requireJS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, requirejs

I'm using requireJS. I have two files, with main app configuraction, functions:

**app/main.js**

```
define(["jquery", "jquery_migrate"], function() {
    return {
        bar: function() {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
});
```

and with some events to fire up this function:

**app/events.js**

```
require(['main_app'], function(foo) { 
    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
        foo.bar();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and this is routing file:

**app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/libs",
    "paths": {
        "main_app":         "../app/main",
        // global
        "app":              "../app",
        "jquery":           "jquery/jquery",
        "jquery_migrate":   "jquery/jquery_migrate"
    }
});
requirejs([ "app/main", "app/events" ]);
```

I still have `Uncaught Error: Script error for: main_app` and no reponse from click event. Can anybody help? Much thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the the `main_app` key

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/libs",
    "paths": {
        //"main_app":         "../app/main", // I believe this is causing a conflict
        // global
        "app":              "../app", 
        "jquery":           "jquery/jquery",
        "jquery_migrate":   "jquery/jquery_migrate"
    }
});
```

**app/events.js**

```
require(['app/main'], function(foo) { 
    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
        foo.bar();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this error `Uncaught Error: Script error for: main_app`, your scripts won't execute.

Chances are your `require.config` is not loaded or not pointing to the correct path. Verify in the Networks tabs what file is actually loaded and then fix it.

If the paths are correct, then you have a JS syntax error somewhere in your code.

Comment: all scripts loading corectly, also i don't see any syntax error :(